# Cannot put JSON into NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to get my JSON into an `NSDictionary`. I am doing the following:

```
 NSData *innerData = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSLog(@"Inner Description %@", innerData);

                NSError* error;
                NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:innerData 
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
                NSLog(@"dict: %@",json);
```

It keeps crashing on the creation of dictionary with this error.

```
-[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8d6100
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is the second question that arises out of the misbelief that `NSJSONSerialization` does a shallow parse only. What makes people believe this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

innerData is an NSDictionary during runtime, not NSData as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`[json objectForKey:@"data"]` is already a dictionary and not NSData.

Answer (score 0):

Your object `json` is probably returning an `NSDictionary` on `[json objectForKey:@"data"];`

Check the actual object type of your `innerData`